# Adding Tracking to Dotdigital Form

Tags: forms, events, google-analytics, tracking, goal-tracking

We are using Dotdigital as our CRM system, and we are adding forms onto our magento website.  We are trying to track these forms in google analytics, but we cannot figure out how to setup the event/goal.  We have added the google analytics tracking to the form, but we are not collecting any data in google analytics.  We have gone off the article but Dotdigital cannot assist further since all data will be collected in GA.    Here is the article we are going off but not sure if there are any articles in GA we can review also.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

[image]

We added the script but are seeing no results

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you using is that GA4 and form events should be tracked. If you using Gtag please follow this article - https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-form-tracking/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).